# Get the context of Intent.RINGTONE_PICKER in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, ringtone

I'm currently developing a custom ringtone picker app that handles the RingonePicker Intent from Android. When I execute "Set Ringtone" from the android main ringtone settings I get data like this:

```
android.intent.extra.ringtone.TYPE:1
android.intent.extra.ringtone.SHOW_DEFAULT:false
android.intent.extra.ringtone.EXISTING_URI:...
android.intent.extra.ringtone.SHOW_SILENT:true
android.intent.extra.ringtone.TITLE:Phone ringtone
```

and when I click "Set ringtone" from a contact menu I only get

```
android.intent.extra.ringtone.SHOW_DEFAULT:true
android.intent.extra.ringtone.EXISTING_URI:...
android.intent.extra.ringtone.TYPE:1
android.intent.extra.ringtone.SHOW_SILENT:false
```

My question is how can I know in which context im running?, and if I'm setting a contact ringtone, which contact is it? There seems to be no support for this and I need to store the contact number and the ringtone selected.

By calling `getCallingPackage()` I'm able to see if it was called from "android ringtone" or "contact ringtone", still I cannot get what contact the user choose